# convert char to text

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

```
SELECT code, year, term, name
FROM ........
```

Here, what I get is code(char), year(int), term(text), name(char)
But what I want is code(text), year(int), term(text), name(text)

what should I do? It seems function text() can only use once?

Comment: Try `code::TEXT, name::TEXT`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try use CAST:

```
SELECT cast(code as text), year, term, cast(name as text)
    FROM ........
    cast(i as text)
```

[THIS](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/) is example use cast in different cases